# How To Set serializableCheck: false For Specific Slice ReduxToolKit React Native

Tags: react-native, middleware, redux-toolkit

I cannot find a way to set serializableCheck to false only for specific slice.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {    
    ApiSignalMenu: ApiSignalMenuSlice.reducer,
    ApiSignalData: ApiSignalDataSlice.reducer,
    ApiHistoricalMenu: ApiHistoricalMenuSlice.reducer,
    ApiHistoricalYearData: ApiHistoricalYearDataSlice.reducer,
    ApiUpProbabilityMenu: ApiUpProbabilityMenuSlice.reducer,    
    ApiUpProbabilityData: ApiUpProbabilityDataSlice.reducer,
    ApiMoverData: ApiMoverDataSlice.reducer,
    ApiChartingMenu: ApiChartingMenuSlice.reducer,    
    ApiChartingData: ApiChartingDataSlice.reducer,
    ApiTicker: ApiTickerSlice.reducer    
  },
  // middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  //   getDefaultMiddleware({      
  //     serializableCheck: false
  //   }
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredPaths: ['ApiMoverData.apiData.0'],      
    }
  }) 
});
```

I have array data in : **ApiMoverData**

If I set : **ignoredPaths: ['ApiMoverData.apiData.0'],**

Then I got error again for A **non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0`. Value:, ApiMoverData**

**And**

Then I got error again for Then I got error again for **A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `ApiMoverData.apiData.0`**

**ApiMoverData.apiData.1,** Then **ApiMoverData.apiData.2,** again.

How to set serializableCheck to false to all my array data in specific slice ?

This post : [Is there a way to set the serializableCheck to false for one reducer only in redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336753/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-serializablecheck-to-false-for-one-reducer-only-in-red)

did not tell a specific answer.

Thank You

**EDIT :**

My structure data looks like this :

```
Array [
  ApiMoverData {
    "change": "1,43",
    "company": "Garuda Maintenance Facility Aero Asia Tbk.",
    "id": 0,
    "last": "71",
    "ticker": "GMFI",
    "value": "99.343.200",
    "volume": "13.992",
  },
  ApiMoverData {
    "change": "1,44",
    "company": "Kimia Farma Tbk.",
    "id": 1,
    "last": "1.765",
    "ticker": "KAEF",
    "value": "956.208.000",
    "volume": "5.433",
  }
]
```

If I set : **ignoredPaths: ['ApiMoverData.apiData']**

Then I got error again for A **non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0`. Value:, ApiMoverData**

**And**

Then I got error again for **A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `ApiMoverData.apiData.0`**

**ApiMoverData.apiData.1,** Then **ApiMoverData.apiData.2,** again.

**Same Error**

Comment: `ignoredPaths: ['ApiMoverData.apiData']`

Comment: Thats not working. I got error

Comment: "I got error" enables nobody to help you. What error?

Comment: @phry I have edit my question. Please help check it for me. Thank You

Comment: Instead of just turning the checks out - have you checked *why* that data is non-serializable? Are those class instances? Because that warning has usually a good reason and you should not store class instances in your Redux store, but make a plain object copy of them before storing them.

Comment: @phry yes it is a class instances. So what is the solution ?

Comment: Do not store class instances in Redux. That is what the whole error message is about. Take the data from that class instance, put it into a non-class JavaScript object and store that.

Comment: @phry yes the probelm indeed using class instance. But i want to uae class instance because it look more tidy in code. But reduxtoolkit doesnt allow it. So thats why i want to disable non seriazable but i am afraid if i disable the serializable global it will effect negative in future. So thas why i want to disable just for specific slice in redux toolkit

Comment: It will also have negative effects if you disable it only for that slice: You will not be able to use redux-persist, other middleware might get random bugs, the class instances will not be frozen, so they might change internally without triggering rerender, the devtools might crash.
This error message has a very good reason. The second error message you were getting was because you do not only have those values in your store, but also in your actions - so you would have to exclude both state and the action.

Comment: @phry Thank you for your explanation. It seem i must change the model data and use a plain array or object data without class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recomended by @phry do not use class instance in redux-toolkit. Because it will effect negative in future. Also we will not be able to use Redux-Persist. Just use non-class javascript object and store that.